# HP-Unix: C-shell:Disk space checking

Tags: unix, diskspace

I have 10 devices that using hp-ux and i want to check the disk space in each devices.
my requirement is if the space more than 90%, the info of device ans space will be save to a log.
this is list of device and ip address which i set as variable ipadd:

```
lo1 100.45.32.43
lot2 100.45.32.44
lot3 100.45.32.44
lot4 100.45.32.45
lot5 100.45.32.46 
and so on..
```

This is my script so far :

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set ipaddress = (`awk '{print $2}' "ipadd"`)
set device = (`awk '{print $1}' "ipadd"`)

@ j = 1
while ($j <= $#ipaddress)
   echo $ipaddress
   set i = 90        # Threshold set at 90%
   set max = 100
   while ($i <= $max)         
      rsh $ipaddress[$j] bdf | grep /dev/vg00 | grep $i% \
      |awk '{   file=substr($6,index($6,"/") + 1,length($6)); print "WARNING: $device[$j]:/" file " has reached " $5 ". Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY..." >> "/scripts/space." file ".file"}'    
      @ i++
   end
   @ j++
end
```

The output after bdf:

```
/dev/vg00/lvol2    15300207 10924582 28566314   79% /
/dev/vg00/lvol4      42529   23786   25510   55% /stand
```

The output at terminal after exec the script:

```
100.45.32.43
100.45.32.44
```

The output at .file:

```
WARNING: $device[$j]:/ has reached 79%. Perform HouseKeeping   IMMEDIATELY...
```

My question is, is it my looping have something wrong cause only iterates one time only because my .file output only show one device only?
And why $device[$j] not come out in .file output?
or awk have problem?

Thank you for the advice.

Comment: You might try here instead: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: You're doing 11 `rsh`s per host - not very efficient! I'd rethink the solution. The `$device[$j]` is printed as is because it is inside `awk '...'` (single quote - no expansion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tested for each possible percentage between 90 and 100.

Persumably, you'd be OK with code that checks once, and asks 'is device percent greater than 90%'?. So then you don't need the inner loop at all, and you make only 1 connection per machine, try

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set ipaddress = (`awk '{print $2}' "ipadd"`)
set device = (`awk '{print $1}' "ipadd"`)
@ j = 1
set i = 90        # Threshold set at 90%
while ($j <= $#ipaddress)
   echo $ipaddress
   echo "#dbg: ipaddress[$j]=${ibpaddress[$j]}"
   rsh $ipaddress[$j] bdf \
   | awk -v thresh="$i" -v dev="$device[$j]" \
      '/\/dev\/vg00/ { \
          sub(/%/,"",$5) \
          if ($5 > thresh) { \
           file=substr($6,index($6,"/") + 1,length($6)) \
           print "WARNING: " dev ":/" file " has reached " $5 ". Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY..." >> "/scripts/space." file ".file" \
       }\
     }'    
   @ j++
end
```

Sorry, but I don't have a `csh` available to dbl-chk for syntax errors.

So here is a one liner that we determined worked in your environment.

```
rsh $ipaddress[$j] bdf | nawk -v thresh="$i" -v dev="$device[$j]" '/\/dev\/vg00/ { sub(/%/,"",$5) ; if ($5 > thresh) { file=substr($6,index($6,"/") + 1,length($6));print "#dbg:file="file; print "WARNING: " dev ":/" file " has reached " $5 ". Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY..." >> "/scripts/space.file.TMP" } }'
```

I don't have a system with `bdf` available. Change the two references to `$5` in the `sub()` and `if` test to match the field-number of the output that has the percentage you want to test.

Note that `-v var="value"` is the standard way to pass a variable value from the shell to an `awk` script that is enclosed in single-quotes.

Be careful that any '\' chars at the end of a line *are* the last chars, no trailing space or tabs, or you'll get an indecipherable error msg. ;-)

IHTH

Comment: the '\' is included in the script?

Comment: @larrey : yes and actually, as I don't have `csh` to test with, my memory is now telling me that each line of the `awk` script should have a '\' char as well. Let me know if you get syntax errors.

Comment: @larrey : see version with '\' for each `awk` line. I found one of my old `csh` scripts and I'm now pretty certain that each line break needs to have the continuation char `('/')` on the end. Hmm, and I now notice that you're using `HP-Unix`. so my experience is with Sun, and I know there were significant differences between the 2 Unix versions. I think I have written a very "plain-vanilla" solution, but there may be traps I'm unaware of ;-) Use comments to send me error msgs.

Comment: and you're sure there are no trailing space/tabs after '\' at the end-of-lines? If so, then try folding the `awk` script onto one line. Now that I have a fresh set of eyes, I'll review my posting and see if there are any other fixes required.

Comment: If you're folding the `awk` script onto one line, you remove the '\' chars. For some lines in there you need `;` to separate the cmds. `. . . "",$5) ; if` ... AND `...length($6)) ; print ...`

Comment: if i exec exactly the code you give me..just copy and paste it, i got error $device undefined variable

Comment: you'll need to use your code at the top of  your Q that sets `$devices[]`. Good luck.

Comment: the output still $devices[$j] not come out..or should just put $device[]?

Comment: eror
`
10.54.10.237 10.54.10.135
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
10.54.10.237 10.54.10.135
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1`

Comment: sorry, going to bed. Will check w you tomorrow. I don't know, does HP-Unix have `nawk` like Sun? If so, change `awk` for `nawk`. Bye for now.

Comment: I"m not sure, did  you "fold" up the complete `awk` script onto one line? If so go one step further, and make `rsh .... | awk ...` all on one line too. Do you understand about where to put the `;`s? Maybe edit your Q and add (at the bottom, your version of the my script.? Thanks for your patience and good luck.

Comment: i stiill got this 
`WARNING: $device[$j]:/stand has reached 55%. Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY...
WARNING: $device[$j]:/stand has reached 56%. Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY..`

Comment: OK, is `/dev/vg00` the only `/dev` you should be looking at? Also, see edited code above for debugging added. It is marked as `#dbg`. Thanks.

Comment: got this error `awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1`

Comment: when i man awk..
` Variables assigned in this manner are not avail-
     able inside a BEGIN rule, and are assigned after  previously
     specified files have been read.`

Comment: A. I'm interested to know what the output of `echo "#dbg ...."` is please. B. Did you make the "fold" everything to one line as requested? C. Why do you think that `man awk` section applies to this code. There is no `BEGIN` block. D. If you have `nawk` on your system you should be using that. You may (eventually) get a better error msg. E. relating back to point B above, right now the problem is something to do with the single-quoting of the script. F. I don't think it will solve the immediate problem but change top-line to `#!/bin/csh -fb`. Going to bed. TTYT.

Comment: #dbg: ipaddress[$j]=${ibpaddress[$j]}..this ibpaddress[$j] typo rite..i change to ipaddress .. the output #dbg: ipaddress[1]=10.54.10.237...
B. Did you make the "fold" everything to one line as requested?
mean y that,is it do like this??
` rsh $ipaddress[$j] bdf \| nawk -v thresh="$i" -v dev="$device[$j]" \'/\/dev\/vg00/ { \ sub(/%/,"",$5) \ if ($5 > thresh) { \file=substr($6,index($6,"/") + 1,length($6)) \print "WARNING: " dev ":/" file " has reached " $5 ". Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY..." >> "/scripts/space." file ".file" \}\}' `
..make it to one line?

Comment: try `rsh $ipaddress[$j] bdf | nawk -v thresh="$i" -v dev="$device[$j]" \'/\/dev\/vg00/ { sub(/%/,"",$5) ; if ($5 > thresh) { file=substr($6,index($6,"/") + 1,length($6));print "WARNING: " dev ":/" file " has reached " $5 ". Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY..." > "/scripts/space." file ".file" } }'` . Good luck.

Comment: still got this error Unmatched '.. sorry for bothering you

Comment: Arg, missed a '\' char that needs to be removed. Try `rsh $ipaddress[$j] bdf | nawk -v thresh="$i" -v dev="$device[$j]" '/\/dev\/vg00/ { sub(/%/,"",$5) ; if ($5 > thresh) { file=substr($6,index($6,"/") + 1,length($6));print "WARNING: " dev ":/" file " has reached " $5 ". Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY..." > "/scripts/space." file ".file" } }'`

Comment: i dont know what wrong with it..still got error..
`nawk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
        /\/dev\/vg00/ { sub(/%/,"",$5) ; if ($5 > thresh) { file=substr($6,index($6,"/") + 1,length($6));print "WARNING: " dev ":/" file " has reached " $5 ". Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY..." > "/script/space." >>>  file <<<  ".file" } }`

Comment: OK, lets remove the awk variable `file` from the picture and use a hard-coded name, and see if that gets us past the syntax errors. (see what I mean about better error messages? ;-) ). Try  `rsh $ipaddress[$j] bdf | nawk -v thresh="$i" -v dev="$device[$j]" '/\/dev\/vg00/ { sub(/%/,"",$5) ; if ($5 > thresh) { file=substr($6,index($6,"/") + 1,length($6));print "WARNING: " dev ":/" file " has reached " $5 ". Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY..." > "/scripts/space.file.TMP" } }'` . Good luck.

Comment: no error..but in space.file.TMP.. the output `WARNING: lot10:/ has reached 51. Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY...
WARNING: lot10:/stand has reached 56. Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY...`  it shows only for the last device

Comment: `rsh $ipaddress[$j] bdf | nawk -v thresh="$i" -v dev="$device[$j]" '/\/dev\/vg00/ { sub(/%/,"",$5) ; if ($5 > thresh) { file=substr($6,index($6,"/") + 1,length($6));print "#dbg:file="file; print "WARNING: " dev ":/" file " has reached " $5 ". Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY..." >> "/scripts/space.file.TMP" } }'` .Try that. Hoping that you'll see separate output `#dbg:file=something` AND that you'll get all records in file. Did you change code to test for 51 %? Good luck.

Comment: `WARNING: lot1:/ has reached 79. Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY...
WARNING: lot1:/stand has reached 55. Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY...
WARNING: lot2:/ has reached 51. Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY...
WARNING: lot2:/stand has reached 56. Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY...`
yes..i changed to value i to 40 so i can see the .tmp file..this is the output that i want..thanks for assist me for this task...n im sorry for bothering you..thank u so muchh...

Comment: What was the output on `#dbg:file=...`? Also I'll update my A with the one-liner from above. Can you please accept my answer. The green chk mark near the top left of my A. Thanks.

Comment: Also note that `>>` means append. So each time this script runs, it will continue adding new input to the bottom of the file. Probably not what you want. I'd recommend adding an `rm /scripts/space.*.file` *before* the `while` loop starts. Good luck.

Comment: output for #dbg: ipaddress[$j]=${ipaddress[$j]}
`#dbg: ipaddress[1]=10.54.10.237`

#dbg:file="file

`#dbg:file=
#dbg:file=stand`

oo..i see..thanks once again